# Drupal 6: custom class for menu ul, no wrapping DIVs around the menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

For a menu I need a custom css class for the ul tag. And I don't need the wrapping DIVs around the menu (block-menu... and content).

I need this only for primary-links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "page.tpl.php" of your custom theme (might not work if you use a contributed theme that makes override on "theme_links" core function or alter "$primary_links" variable) just do :

```
print theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' => 'yourclass'));
```

This just prints a "ul li" structure without wrapper. This is exactly what the "garland" default core theme actually does.

Check "garland" source code at line "50" (click "view source" in the page): https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes!garland!page.tpl.php/6

More on theme_links: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_links/6

Comment: That looks good. But in my theme it doesn't work. I used the same code as in garland theme.

When it switch to garland all works fine.

I can't see any function in template.php of garland theme which could this code make working.

Comment: Great, now it works. 'primary links' was deactivated in theme settings.

Thanks for this help!

Comment: My next problem: I get only the first level of the menu. I don't get menu links of the sublevels.

Comment: In that case you must use "$menu_name = variable_get('menu_primary_links_source', 'primary-links');
  print menu_tree($menu_name);" (https://drupal.org/node/68578) but you won't be able to add a custom class as easily as before. In that case "ul" class is "menu". However you could still wrap a div around your menu with a custom class (for css/js targetting)